# How to connect LYNC API

Tags: lync

I am new to Lync. When I run

```
Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient client = LyncClient.GetClient();
```

on my local computer, I get an error saying

> 'The host process is not running'.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

The Lync Client API is basically a "remote control" API to remotely control the Lync/Skype for Business Client.

So what it means by 'The host process is not running' is that Lync.exe is not running.  If you run Lync.exe and then call LyncClient.GetClient(), it should work.

Comment: Thanks Shane for your suggestion